# SQL Server 2008 R2 full version installed but Management Studio is Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Full Package(64bit).BUT after that i see SQL Server Management Studio express installed(database Engine is SQL Server Express).In the other services such as intergration,Analysis,Reporting services are Full version.

So.. whats the error ? Can anyone direct me to install SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Full version

EDIT :
In this first picture shows you normally my SQL Server Management Studio connects.(Only Connect using EXPRESS Version)
[image: Login with SQL SERVER Management Studio Express 2008]

In the second picture shows you the error.

[image]

But When i connect to INtergration services and other service i can login to full version using CHATHU-2 Server Instance

Comment: In object explorer > connect, try and find the full instance in the server name dropdown or using <browse for more>

Comment: @Paul McCowat but not connected.only connected sql server management studio express

Comment: Where are you seeing the database engine is SQL express.  On my laptop I have SSMS from express tools but it doesn't say it is express and I can connect to full SQL Server and express.  perhaps you could take a screenshot.

Comment: @PaulMcCowat Paste some pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop your SQL Server Instance.SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) & Start SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)
go there services.msc

Answer (score 1):

Management Studio is a stand alone application, so it does not matter that it states Express.
Did you Install anything prior to SQL like SharePoint or Visual Studio?
If you did that would be why you see express. SharePoint and Visual Studio install SQL Express upon their install.

Comment: I first install SQL Server 2008 Express Edition+ Management Studio Express. After that i Remove that edition & Re-install SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Full Version.BUT all other services are Full version.Only Management studio is express.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you only have to remove the \SQLEXPRESS from the server name textbox or click on it's drop down arrow, browse for servers and see what is there.

You could also run services.msc, look for SQL Server services and see what is there, named instances are normally in brackets.